# How to obtain an expanded polynomial expresion with decreasing order of powers?

Tags: series-expansion

When you type:

```
Expand[12 (x - 1/3) (x + 1/2) (x - 1/2)]
```

you obtain:
     1 - 3 x - 4 x^2 + 12 x^3

The question is: 
How to obtain the expresion expanded in decreassing order of powers?
so
    12 x^3 - 4 x^2 - 3 x + 1